# Expandable List View groupState Indicator

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to make an indicator to tell if the group view is expanded or collapsed, I created a global imageView

```
private ImageView listStateIndicator;
```

and intialized it in getGroupView:

```
listStateIndicator = convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_state);
```

then set its drawable in
 onGroupExpanded:

```
listStateIndicator.setImageDrawable(mActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.expanded));
```

and onGroupCollapsed:

```
listStateIndicator.setImageDrawable(mActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.collapsed));
```

but nothing happens when the group is expanded or collapsed, what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution in getGroupView I wrote this code:

```
if(isExpanded)
            listStateIndicator.setImageDrawable(mActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.expanded));
        else
            listStateIndicator.setImageDrawable(mActivity.getDrawable(R.drawable.collapsed));
```